# The Distance between two points in a hypothetical universe.

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-topology

I have a hypothetical universe where the distance between two points in spacetime is defined as:$$ds^2 =−(\phi^2 t^2)dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$Where $\phi$ has units of $km\space s^{-2}$.  The space in this universe grows quadratically with time (and, as I understand it, probably isn’t Minkowski spacetime).  A particle travelling at the speed of causality, c, will follow this contour from point O to point P.

[image]

Given the time between point O and point Q, is it possible to find the distance from point P to point Q (e.g. does a function exist such that $f(\Delta t) = d_L$)?  If so, what is that formula?

**EDIT:** I understand that in Minkowski space $ds^2 = -c^2\space dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$, but in this metric, space grows quadratically. In Minkowski space, if you were $3 \times 10^6\space km$ away from an emitter and it sent out a photon, the photon would arrive in exactly one second (following a null geodesic). In this metric, as the photon travels to you, the space in between you and the emitter expands - like a moving sidewalk - so the photon will arrive in something more than a second. As this universe gets older and the space between the objects gets larger, the problem is exacerbated. In fact, if the universe gets old enough, travel between two distant objects becomes impossible, so I have a tough time seeing how the speed of light is related to a null geodesic in this universe.

Comment: This space is isometric to (an open subset of) Minkowski spacetime, via the coordinate change $s = \frac{1}{2} \phi t^2$.

Comment: Looks like a nice subwoofer!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a physicist nor a mathematician that knows about Minkowski Spaces, but here is a stab anyway.

It seems that the speed of causality for your universe is $c(t)=\phi t$.  So the speed of the particle is $c(t)= dx/dt$.   We simply get

$$dx/dt= \phi t$$
$$x_P-x_O= \phi (t_P^2-t_O^2)/2$$

So the distance travelled is merely $\phi (t_P^2-t_O^2)/2$ where $t_O$ is the time at point O and $t_P$ is the time at point P.

Comment: I don't agree.  The speed of causality in this universe is c, or roughly $3.0 \times 10^5\space km\space s^{-1}$.  Could you please explain why you think causality is related to the tangent of this space?  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I think the speed of causality is dictated by the coefficient in front of $dt^2$ in the formula for $ds^2$.  I am basing that thought on the argument at [https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Special_Relativity/Faster_than_light_signals,_causality_and_Special_Relativity].  As stated above, I am not very knowledgable in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my maiden attempt. Consider $$ds_{OP}^2 =−(\phi^2 t^2)dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$
dividing by $dt^2$,
 we get
$$\frac{ds_{OP}^2}{dt^2} = −(\phi^2 t^2) + \frac{dx^2}{dt^2} + \frac{dy^2}{dt^2} + \frac{dz^2}{dt^2}$$, Now notice that all the rate of change is just $c$, the speed of causality.
So we have,
$$c^2 = −(\phi^2 t^2) +  c^2 + c^2 +c^2$$
$$=>\phi^2 t^2 = 2c^2 $$
$$=>t = +\frac{\sqrt{2}c}{\phi} or -\frac{\sqrt{2}c}{\phi}$$
So the time taken to traverse a distance for a particle travelling at $c$ from any two points is based only on $\phi$.

Now consider for points A and B,
$$-\phi^2 \int_{t_A}^{t_B}\int_{t_A}^{t_B}{t^2.dt.dt}$$
$$=>-\frac{\phi^2}{3} (\int_{t_A}^{t_B}{t_B^3}.dt - \int_{t_A}^{t_B}{t_A^3}.dt)$$
$$=>-\frac{\phi^2}{3} ({t_B^3}(t_B - t_A) - {t_A^3}(t_B - t_A))$$
Simplifying,
$$=>-\frac{\phi^2}{3} ((t_B - t_A)({t_B^3} - {t_A^3}))->(1)$$

Now integrating both sides of eqn. 
$$ds_{OQ}^2 =−(\phi^2 t^2)dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$
with 
$$\int_{t_O}^{t_Q}\int_{t_O}^{t_Q}$$, w.r.t $dt$ we get from (1)
$$ds_{OQ}^2 =-\frac{\phi^2}{3} ((t_Q - t_O)({t_Q^3} - {t_O^3}))+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 + C_{1}$$
Now, Choose $$t_O = 0$$ to be the start time of a particle starting from O towards Q, then $$ => \Delta{t} = t_Q-t_O => \Delta{t} = t_Q$$, now consider another particle reaching Q from P at *exactly* the same *time* $$t_Q = \Delta{t}$$ with possibly different velocity but starting at time $$t_P = 0$$, so
$$ds_{PQ}^2 =-\frac{\phi^2}{3} ((t_Q - t_P)({t_Q^3} - {t_P^3}))+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 + C_{2}$$
$$=>ds_{PQ}^2 =-\frac{\phi^2}{3} (({t_Q^4}))+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 + C_{2}$$
$$=>ds_{PQ}^2 =-\frac{\phi^2}{3} ((\Delta{t}^4))+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 + C_{2}$$
$$=>d_L^2 =-\frac{\phi^2}{3} ((\Delta{t}^4))+\int_{x_p}^{x_q}\int_{x_p}^{x_q}dx^2+\int_{y_p}^{y_q}\int_{y_p}^{y_q}dy^2+\int_{z_p}^{z_q}\int_{z_p}^{z_q}dz^2$$
$$=-\frac{\phi^2}{3}(\Delta{t}^4)+(x_p-x_q)^2+(y_p -y_q)^2 + (z_p - z_q)^2$$

Comment: Your first step assumes $\frac {ds}{dt}$ is the speed of causality.  Why do you make that assumption?  What is Capital C? and what am I supposed to do with $dx^2 + dy^2 +dz^2$ in the final formula?

Comment: $c$ is a constant ( speed of light is constant) as per Special relativity for all frames of reference. capital $C_2$ is a integration constant. gets cancelled in the last line. I have clarifies the last line as well

Comment: I still don't understand why you assume $\frac {ds}{dt}$ is the speed of causality.  What aspect if this metric allows you to make that jump?

Comment: In the problem statement you said a particle traveling from O to P travels at speed of causality $c$.That means the overall distance by the time taken is $c$

Comment: The speed of the particle on this surface has nothing to do with the surface tangent.  I could be travelling at 50 MPH and that wouldn't change $\frac {ds}{dt}$.